# How to manage order of init services in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

in nestjs app, I have 2 modules:
ServiceModule and ParamStoreModule

- Param Store module has a ParamStoreService which loads Data from AWS Param Store (i load all params only once and store them in a map)
- Service Module has a Work Service which during initialization (in constructor) requires a parameter from this ParamStoreService, but this value is loaded after the Worker service is created

Is there a way to create this Work Service after the values from Param Store will be loaded? Can we manage the order of creating Services?

regards

Comment: The order of initializing modules is based on the order of the imports array in the root module(i.e. `AppModule`).

However, I would suggest using `useFactory` for initializing in such a case and passing your custom parameters.